# Is using an Eagle Whistle considered as wearing/carrying it for the purpose of Telekinesis?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

The description of the [Eagle Whistle](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/eagle-whistle) from *Tales From the Yawning Portal* p. 228 states:

> *Wondrous Item, Rare*
>
> While you blow an eagle whistle continuously, you can fly twice as fast as your walking speed. You can blow the whistle continuously for a number of rounds equal to 5 + five times your Constitution modifier (minimum of 1 round) or until you talk, hold your breath, or start suffocating. A use of the whistle also ends if you land. If you are aloft when you stop blowing the whistle, you fall. The whistle has three uses. It regains expended uses daily at dawn.

While you are blowing the eagle whistle, are you considered as wearing or carrying it for the purpose of the [*telekinesis*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/telekinesis) spell ?

> **Object.** You can try to move an object that weighs up to 1,000 pounds. If the object isn’t being worn or carried, you automatically move it up to 30 feet in any direction, but not beyond the range of this spell. If the object is worn or carried by a creature, you must make an ability check with your spellcasting ability contested by that creature’s Strength check. If you succeed, you pull the object away from that creature and can move it up to 30 feet in any direction but not beyond the range of this spell.

This is important, as a creature flying in the air thanks to the Eagle Whistle would certainly not want its beloved whistle to be automatically snatched away.

Answer (score 12):

## Carried

The Whistle is on your person and is being used by your person. This is identical to any other object that a creature may be carrying such as ropes, backpacks, and weapons.

The Whistle is not floating, it is either in your hand, in your mouth (if actively being used), or being stowed somewhere on your person.

### Carried away

If someone were to cast Telekinesis on it, it could absolutely be taken away from the creature using it (pending the failed ability contest.)

Answer (score 10):

## Yes, it is worn or carried.

I wouldn't rule just blowing on the whistle counts as wearing it but you are definitely carrying it with you as you fly around. Also you have the benefits of the magical item so it can be counted as being 'worn' between your lips.

If you are the player consider wearing the whistle as a necklace. That would help avoid a discussion about this with the DM.